# What does it mean to "bootstrap" an Angular application?

Tags: angular

There are a number of places in the Angular docs where the word "bootstrap" appears as a link. The link takes you [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/appmodule.html#!#main).

I don't see anything in the linked section that actually says what the word "bootstrap" means. As far as I can tell it's just a synonym for "start", but I don't know if I'm right about that.

I know that you can do something like `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);` and it will "bootstrap" your app using the `AppModule`. That doesn't really tell me the meaning of the word, though.

So what does **bootstrap** mean, exactly?

Comment: 1) Why was this question downvoted, 2) if your comment answers my question, why not just put it as an answer

Comment: I didn't downvote your question. My comment just shows that it is described in article you provided

Comment: Oh, yeah, I wasn't asking why you downvoted the question, I was just generally asking why it was downvoted. If you put your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: If you're looking for a linguistic explanation, I suspect it comes from the phrase "pulling yourself up by your bootstraps" - that is, the program sets itself up and loads without any external input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bootstrapping process sets up the execution environment, digs the root AppComponent out of the module's bootstrap array, creates an instance of the component and inserts it within the element tag identified by the component's selector.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Did you find that diagram somewhere or create it yourself? If you found it somewhere, where? If you created it yourself, nice work. :)

Comment: It is from my private presentation

Answer (score 3):

I, too, had this question because I had forgotten what it means. I was getting especially confused with the Bootstrap CSS framework. Your original question asked the meaning from a more general meaning, and not just with respect to Angular.

Bootstrapping is actually an old computer term and I think [Wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping) is decent:

> In general, **bootstrapping** usually refers to a self-starting process that is supposed to proceed without external input. In [computer technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_technology) the term (usually shortened to **booting**) usually refers to the process of loading the basic software into the memory of a computer after power-on or general reset, especially the [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) which will then take care of loading other software as needed.
>
> The term appears to have originated in the early 19th-century United States (particularly in the phrase "pull oneself over a fence by one's bootstraps") to mean an absurdly impossible action, an [adynaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adynaton).

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for because it gives a great definition of Bootstrapping as a verb. Other places told what it did, but not what the verb meant.

Comment: For some reason I never made the connection with "booting up" a computer, so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge bootstrapping an app would bascially mean from where it should begin the execution or which is the file to be executed first. In this case **bootstrapModule(AppModule);** means that AppModule is the Module which has all the information about the app and the execution must begin there.