# Display content of template doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular-templatecache

I'm new with angular 2 , I have generated a component with this command

```
ng generate component hello
```

and all files are generated and **app.module.ts** is updated.

in the **index.html** I have added this

```
<app-hello></app-hello>
```

but the web page become blank, nothing appear.

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello/hello.component';

@NgModule({
 declarations: [
 AppComponent,
 HelloComponent
],
imports: [
BrowserModule
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[image]

Comment: Try replacing `bootstrap: [AppComponent]` with `bootstrap: [HelloComponent]`

Comment: We list components in bootstrap to tell angular that these components are our starting points. It means that angular will compile these components in a special way(generate Host factory) and will seek elements which satisfies components selectors. Then inside these elements will be placed component template.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44077178/what-does-it-mean-to-bootstrap-an-angular-application/44077696#44077696

Comment: just change the tag for your index to the bootstrap main component <app></app>

Answer (score 0):

Well, inside index you can print only the component you have in 'bootstrap'. Now, app.component.html is your main html file where you can put other components. You can't do this in index.html.